# Building Qt5 from source: QtWebEngineCore module will not be built. Tool gperf is required to build QtWebEngine

Tags: qt, qt5, cross-compiling

I kind of gave all information in the title.
I've cross-compiled Qt5.15.3 and I tried to build CQtDeployer with it and CQtDeployer requires qtwebengine.

Initially I didn't need the qtwebengine, but as I said i now need it to build cqtdeployer I've installed everything needed for QtWebEngine specified here: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git and just did the following:

```
cd qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtwebengine
../qtbase/bin/qmake -r .
make
```

but building QtWebEngineCore and QtPdf fails giving the following messages although `gperf` is installed:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/xch/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtwebengine/src/core'
QtWebEngineCore module will not be built. Tool gperf is required to build QtWebEngine.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/xch/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtwebengine/src/core'
cd pdf/ && ( test -e Makefile || /xch/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtbase/bin/qmake -o Makefile /xch/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtwebengine/src/pdf/pdf.pro ) && make -f Makefile 
make[2]: Entering directory '/xch/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtwebengine/src/pdf'
QtPdf will not be built. Tool gperf is required to build QtPdf.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/xch/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtwebengine/src/pdf'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/xch/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.3/qtwebengine/src'
```

edit:

**gperf --version**

```bash
GNU gperf 3.0.4
Copyright (C) 1989-1998, 2000-2004, 2006-2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Douglas C. Schmidt and Bruno Haible.
/bin/sh: 1: parse_git_branch: not found
```

Comment: Can this be related to me doing all these in a chroot?